# SQL Binomial Distribution/Arithmetical Overflow

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I created a function for a cumulative binomial distribution.  It works well for extremely modest sample sizes, but I get a arithmetical overflow on larger samples.

[image: Binomial Distribution]

The largest culprit is the n!.  In excel 170! = 7.3E+306.  171! = #NUM!

Excel has an internal function that calculates binomial distribution, and it works with ns much, much larger than 170.

Is there something I can do to limit the magnitude of the #s generated?

EDIT: I played with this

```
SET @probout = 2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10*11*12
```

Worked fine

```
SET @probout = 2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10*11*12*13/10000
```

Resulted in overflow

Function below.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[binomdist_cumulative] 
    (   
    @n      int
    ,@k     int
    ,@p     float 
    )
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN

    -- Local Variable Declarations
    -- ---------------------------
    DECLARE         @kfac           float
                    ,@nfac          float
                    ,@nkfac         float
                    ,@i             float
                    ,@f             int
                    ,@probout       float

    SET @i = 0
    SET @f = 0
    SET @nfac = 0
    SET @kfac = 0
    SET @nkfac = 0
    SET @probout = 0

    WHILE @i <= @k
    BEGIN


--k!
        SET @f = @i-1
        SET @kfac = @i
        IF @kfac > 0
        BEGIN
            WHILE @f > 0
            BEGIN
                SET @kfac = @kfac*@f
                SET @f = @f -1
            END
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @kfac = 1
        END

--n!
        SET @f = @n-1
        SET @nfac = @n
        IF @nfac > 0
        BEGIN
            WHILE @f > 0
            BEGIN
                SET @nfac = @nfac * @f
                SET @f = @f -1
            END
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @nfac = 1
        END

--(n-k)!
        SET @f = @n-@i-1
        SET @nkfac = @n-@i
        IF @nkfac > 0
        BEGIN
            WHILE @f > 0
            BEGIN
                SET @nkfac = @nkfac * @f
                SET @f = @f -1
            END
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @nkfac = 1
        END

--Accumulate distribution
        SET @probout = @probout + @nfac/(@kfac*@nkfac)*POWER(@p,@i)*POWER(1-@p,@n-@i)

        SET @i = @i+1




    END

    RETURN @probout
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me give you a hint.

If you calculate the full factorials, you are quickly going to get overflows.  If you do an incremental calculation, the you won't.

For instance, instead of calculating (5 // 3) as (5*4*3*2*1) / ((3*2) * (3*2*1)), calculate it as:  (5 / 3) * (4 / 2) * (3 / 3) * (2 / 2) * (1 / 1). . . oh, wait, you can see that the last three terms are all "1".

To be clear, you want to calculate the product of:

```
((n - i) / (n - k - i)
```

For i between 0 and k - 1.  That is, you are dividing the product of *k* consecutive numbers ending in *n* with *k* consecutive numbers starting with 1.

You'll see that this incremental approach will forestall the issues with overflow.

Comment: Thanks!  I think the math is slightly off but I understand the approach.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this still has scale limitations, thought not as bad.  Take a 7/4 example.  We essentially have (7*6*5*4*3*2*1)/(4*3*2*1*3*2*1).  

I wrote the loop to do 7/4*6/3*5/3*4/2*3/2*2/1*1/1 using the biggest denominator available.  

At big enough numbers we essentially wind up with a 2^big resulting in huge numbers.  This eventually gets multiplied by 0.5^big*0.5^big.

So I think I need to incorporate the power terms in that portion of the loop as well...

Comment: @T.Hannah . . . Yes, very true.  I was focused on the "choose" part of the equation.